# How can I set loading image during post data processing for jquery ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, loading

The jquery ajax code is:

```
$("#id_btnpolls").click(function(){ 
    var valCheckedRadio = $('input[name=data[distributions]]:checked').val();
    //alert(valCheckedRadio);       

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/pollanswers/checkpollanswers",
        data: "valCheckedRadio="+valCheckedRadio,       
        success: function(prm){
            //alert(prm);
            $("#id_color_polls").html(prm);
        }           
    });

})
```

When I click the button, the data is displayed after 5 seconds or so. During that loding period I want to add a loading image. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the CSS + HTML I use for my loading image. I use jQuery to simply add a class that changes the opacity from 1 to 0, in combination with a CSS transition property for a fade effect. The background image for #loader is 220px X 80px and is just a solid color rounded rectangle with the text "loading" on the right hand side. The actual "ajax" spinner img is 60px tall, so that relative positioning and negative margin are there to center the img vertically.

```
   #loader {
        width: 220px;
        height: 80px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        z-index: -1;
        opacity: 0;
        background: url(assets/images/bg-loader.png) no-repeat center center;
        transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
        margin: -40px 0 0 -110px;
    }

    #loader img {position: relative; top: 50%; margin-top: -30px; left: 10px;}

    .loading #loader {z-index: 1000; opacity: 1.0}
```

And the HTML (i got the loader.gif from here http://www.preloaders.net ):

```
    <div id="loader"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/assets/images/loader.gif" /></div>
```

And then your jQuery:

```
$("#id_btnpolls").click(function(){ 
    var $body = $('body'),
         valCheckedRadio = $('input[name=data[distributions]]:checked').val();

    $body.addClass('loading');       

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/pollanswers/checkpollanswers",
        data: "valCheckedRadio="+valCheckedRadio,       
        success: function(prm){
            //alert(prm);
            $("#id_color_polls").html(prm);
            $body.removeClass('loading');
        }           
    });

})
```

Comment: it's the body element. It's easy to select the loading states of other elements by having the loading class on the body. That way any elements you want to hide during loading time can be selected by ".loading .element"

Answer (score 3):

1) Have a holding div for the image, that is normally not visible.

You can do this via css, by adding `visibility:hidden;` (vs `visibility: visible;`), or optionally with `display: none;`

2) In your click handler, make that holding div visible.
3) In the `done` callback, make it invisible again.

[Directly from the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/),

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "script.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: {id : menuId},
  dataType: "html"
});

request.done(function(msg) {
  $("#log").html( msg );
  // hide your loading image div here
});
```

Comment: I can't understand your answer, posting complete example code will be helpful. what is data: {id : menuId} and dataType: "html" and where is the image there?

Comment: @guru, that is an example from the documentation.  It's just an example ajax request.  look at the `done` method where I put the comment in.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [blockUI](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/) plugin for jquery

```
$(document).ajaxStart($.blockUI).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);
```

Answer (score 2):

The HTML and CSS code specified by j-man86 is good. For jQuery you can use the beforeSend function in the AJAX call. **beforeSend** is called before an AJAX request is sent. To hide the loading image use **complete** function of jQuery AJAX which is called after an AJAX request has been completed. So the code will look like:

```
$("#id_btnpolls").click(function(){ 
    var $body = $('body'),
         valCheckedRadio = $('input[name=data[distributions]]:checked').val();

    $body.addClass('loading');       

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/pollanswers/checkpollanswers",
        data: "valCheckedRadio="+valCheckedRadio,
        beforeSend: function(){
            $body.addClass('loading');
        },
        success: function(prm){
            //alert(prm);
            $("#id_color_polls").html(prm);
        },
        complete: function(){
            $body.removeClass('loading');
        }           
    });

})
```

Comment: var $body = $('body');
Good catch guru:)

Comment: You do not need to have the removeClass in the success: as the complete: will be called after that - and even if it errors. +1 for doing it this way (beforeSend/complete) however.  You COULD also do a global jQuery ajax as well using ajaxSend/ajaxComplete.

Comment: You are right Mark Schultheiss. I have removed the removeClass() from success function. Declaring global AJAX configurations are also a good idea.